# Cutting sole plates in place

Tags: walls, doors, framing

I'm framing some longer walls and in one post (I can't find it again) it mentioned it'd be a good idea to not cut the sole plate where doors will be until after the wall is raised.  Is that correct and if so, how would you cut the sole plate after the wall is raised?

Answer (score 1):

There are several techniques. Some simply cut them with a reciprocating saw once the wall is up. This tends to scuff the subfloor in a superficial way. Some cut partway through (full depth with a circular saw from the narrow edge) before the wall is lifted, allowing quick finish cuts with a handsaw later. Some do cut them all out once the wall is built by lifting the plate onto a series of scrap blocks (2x4 on edge). Some do whatever makes sense for a particular scenario.

It's your call. There's no "right" answer. If you have enough help on hand there's no real benefit to waiting until the wall is up. The idea is mostly to maintain stability in a shorthanded situation.

Comment: I find it better to have the bottom plate solid on a long wall, I did have 1 wall break when being tilted up, that was the last time I cut the plate, a very close call for one employee, but Luckaly no one was hurt. The plate is easy to cut with a hand saw , saws all or many other power tools without any real damage to the sub floor or to the saw (I usually lay a piece of scrap veneer if on the sill so I don't wipe out the blade).

Comment: I typically cut mine approx. halfway through on the bottom face especially when the plates are going down on concrete.

Answer (score 0):

I framed for 35 years. Sometimes you'll want to use shorter sole plates as with an overhead garage door when most of the wall is the door opening. Why waste the width of a long overhead door sole plate a when you can instead use a couple of shorter pieces on the ends if possible?

If you can avoid it and for accuracy, never measure and cut top and bottom plate separately When plating a wall. Instead, tack two plates of sufficient length together, flush @ one end and tack with an 8d or 7d nail to hold the two boards together while cutting them. With a small square check and adjust the bevel (degrees) on the saw base to determine that the depth of the cut will be at a right angle to the saw blade. Measure and set the saw to cut as deep as it will. This will cut the first plate and partially cut through the next allowing for a perfect match between the two.

When plating through a door opening it is possible to cut the sole plate after the wall is stood up and plumbed. Leave out, for now, the trimmers while framing the wall when it is in the horizontal position. Most worm drive saw bases are situated so that the edge of the base is 1-1/2" from the edge of the blade. This means you can ride the saw against the king stud leaving 1-1/2" of the sole plate on each side of the door opening. Now you can install the trimmers. I prefer to do this because I like to make sure the door opening is plumb before cutting the bottom plate.